# How can I find $y$ coordinate of a straight line at a specific $x$ value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say I have a straight line between $p_1=(-2, -0.5)$ and $ p_2=(0.25, 0.5)$.

How can I find the value of $y$ when $x=-1$?

I have tried to solve this the whole day without finding an answer, I clearly need help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First, determine the slope $m$ of the line through the given points.

Then, pick one of the points and determine how much $x$ changes when moving from that point to your new value of $x$. We write this as $\Delta x = x_{new}-x_{old}$.

Use the fact that $m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ to get that $\Delta y = m\cdot \Delta x$. You know $m$ and $\Delta x$ from above, so now you know $\Delta y$. That's how much $y$ changes when moving from the chosen point to the new point, that is, $\Delta y = y_{new}-y_{old}$. So you have what you're after:
$$y_{new}=y_{old} + \Delta y$$

Now you do it with the actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a straight line is $$y=a + b x$$ So, just apply to each point

$$-0.5=a-2b$$ $$0.25=a+0.5b$$ Solve for $a$ and $b$ and apply $$?=a - b$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

The straight line joining $(-2,-0.5)$ and $(0.25,0.5)$ is given by
$$y-0.5=\frac{0.5-(-0.5)}{0.25-(-2)}(x-0.25)$$
$$y-0.5=\frac{1}{2.25}(x-0.25)$$
$$2.25y-1.125=x-0.25$$
$$2.25y-x=0.875$$
$$18y-8x=7$$

Now, substituting $x=-1$, we get,
$$18y+8=7$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{18}$$